# Outlining OpenLDAP approach

Tags: ldap, openldap

We're outlining replace the way we are storing our users and clients.

Currently, users are able to access to our platforms using a client. So, we need to store:

User information:

```
id: string
username: string
password: salted hash SHA string.
cn: string
sn, string
mail: string
avatar: image
```

Client information:

```
id: string
name: string
description: string
organization: string
web: url
sshPlublicKey: certificate
avatar: image
```

Otherwise, I need to store which are the clients through which user is able to get access to our platform.

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to find an existing LDAP schema that has all the attributes you want, unless you're prepared to engage in writing your own.

Comment: Could you tell me where am I able to find these schemas?

Comment: In the LDAP RFCs. There are several of them. Search for 'LDAP schema RFC'. I would start with `inetOrgPerson`, although the photo attribute is called `jpegPhoto`, not `avatar`. You will have to make some compromises like this.

Comment: NB the OpenLDAP schemas are in the `schema` directory.